# Split string at first occurrence of an integer in a string

Tags: java, string

I have a bunch of Strings in this format:

```
Barry's Restaurant 100 East Main Street
```

And I want to split the string into two parts:

```
Barry's Restaurant 
100 East Main Street
```

So, I need to split the string at the first occurrence of an integer (the street address). Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: [`yourString.split("\\d+", 1)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int))

Comment: That is simply for the integer 1, correct? Is there a way to do it for ANY integer? Or do I need to do that do split() for each 1 through 9?

Comment: This is **not** for the integer 1, 1 is the limit. Read the documentation please, this should work for all numbers (`\d+` regex).

Comment: @MarounMaroun `Read the documentation please` good idea, because it shows, that argument `1` is not a good idea. It should be `2` :P.

Comment: @Tom Indeed. Long time no Java ;)

Answer (score 8):

If I understand your question, you could do it with something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String line = "Barry's Restaurant 100 East Main Street";
    String[] arr = line.split("\\d+", 2);
    String pt1 = arr[0].trim();
    String pt2 = line.substring(pt1.length() + 1).trim();
    System.out.println(pt1);
    System.out.println(pt2);
}
```

Output is

```
Barry's Restaurant
100 East Main Street
```

Comment: yep, this is just what I needed, thanks a lot! Will accept when I can

Comment: @Harry The most important thing is to understand what's going on here, please refer to the String API to deepen your knowledge.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I do understand, I was just not familiar with the syntax. I will look into it more though, thanks

Answer (score 3):

To avoid having to reconstitute the split values you could use an actual regex:

```
String s = "Barry's Restaurant 100 East Main Street";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("([^\\d]+)(.*)").matcher(s);
if (matcher.matches()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1).trim());
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] name = "abcd2qwer3yuiop".split("\\d+",2);
System.out.println(name.length); // gives 2
System.out.println(name[0]);   // gives abcd   -- length=4
System.out.println(name[1]);   // gives qwer3yuiop  -- length=10
```

Comment: He wants to split it based on first occurrence of an integer. You haven't answered that..

Comment: I have given a solution that splits on basis of space.
To Split on basis of integer, replace  " " with  "\\d+" in the split function. rest code remains same.

Comment: It's better you modify your answer instead of explaining in the comments. As of now your answer is irrelevant to the question. That's why your answer was downvoted.

Comment: Modified the answer as per the qn

Comment: awesome! Glad you decided to continue contributing to this community :)

Comment: But the number '2' has to be printed along with name[1]. This code doesn't satisfy this criteria

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way to split the string without having to re-add the delimiter is to use a regex [look around](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html):

```
String input = "Barry's Restaurant 100 East Main Street";
String[] result = input.split("(?=\\d+)", 2);
System.out.println(name[0]);
System.out.println(name[1]);
```

Output:

```
Barry's Restaurant 
100 East Main Street
```

(there's still a space at the end of Barry's Restaurant)