# Split String at First Occurrence of an Integer using R

Tags: r, regex, string, split, data.table

**Note** I have already read [Split string at first occurrence of an integer in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27827613/split-string-at-first-occurrence-of-an-integer-in-a-string) however my request is different because I would like to use R.

Suppose I have the following example data frame:

```
> df = data.frame(name_and_address =
      c("Mr. Smith12 Some street",
        "Mr. Jones345 Another street",
        "Mr. Anderson6 A different street"))
> df
                  name_and_address
1          Mr. Smith12 Some street
2      Mr. Jones345 Another street
3 Mr. Anderson6 A different street
```

I would like to split the string at the first occurrence of an integer. Notice that the integers are of varying length.

The desired output can be like the following:

```
[[1]]
[1] "Mr. Smith"
[2] "12 Some street",

[[2]]
[1] "Mr. Jones"
[2] "345 Another street",

[[3]]
[1] "Mr. Anderson"
[2] "6 A different street"
```

I have tried the following but I can not get the regular expression correct:

```
# Attempt 1 (Does not work)
library(data.table)
tstrsplit(df,'(?=\\d+)', perl=TRUE, type.convert=TRUE)

# Attempt 2 (Does not work)
library(stringr)
str_split(df, "\\d+")
```

Comment: I guess you wanted to say "the first digit", right?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, yes I would like the split to occur on the first digit of an integer of varying length.

Comment: You might try splitting each line on (zero-width) matches of `(?<!\\\d)(?=\\d+)`.  The positive lookbehind  `(?<!\\d)` asserts that the current string position (think of it as a location between successive characters) is is not preceded by digit. The positive lookahead `(?=\\d+)` asserts that the current string position is followed by one or more digits. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/If36U6/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `tidyr::extract`:

```r
library(tidyr)
df <- df %>% 
    extract("name_and_address", c("name", "address"), "(\\D*)(\\d.*)")
## => df
##           name              address
## 1    Mr. Smith       12 Some street
## 2    Mr. Jones   345 Another street
## 3 Mr. Anderson 6 A different street
```

The `(\D*)(\d.*)` regex matches the following:

- `(\D*)` - Group 1: any zero or more non-digit chars
- `(\d.*)`  - Group 2: a digit and then any zero or more chars as many as possible.

Another solution with `stringr::str_split` is also possible:

```r
str_split(df$name_and_address, "(?=\\d)", n=2)
## => [[1]]
## [1] "Mr. Smith"      "12 Some street"

## [[2]]
## [1] "Mr. Jones"          "345 Another street"

## [[3]]
## [1] "Mr. Anderson"         "6 A different street"
```

The `(?=\d)` positive lookahead finds a location before a digit, and `n=2` tells `stringr::str_split` to only split into 2 chunks max.

Base R approach that does not return anything if there is no digit in the string:

```r
df = data.frame(name_and_address = c("Mr. Smith12 Some street", "Mr. Jones345 Another street", "Mr. Anderson6 A different street", "1 digit is at the start", "No digits, sorry."))

df$name <- sub("^(?:(\\D*)\\d.*|.+)", "\\1", df$name_and_address)
df$address <- sub("^\\D*(\\d.*)?", "\\1", df$name_and_address)
df$name
# => [1] "Mr. Smith"    "Mr. Jones"    "Mr. Anderson" ""             ""
df$address
# => [1] "12 Some street"          "345 Another street"     
#    [3] "6 A different street"    "1 digit is at the start"         ""
```

See [an online R demo](https://ideone.com/rDLvkA). This also supports cases when the first digit is the first char in the string.

Answer (score 4):

I would use `sub` here:

```
df$name <- sub("(\\D+).*", "\\1", df$name_and_address)
df$address <- sub(".*?(\\d+.*)", "\\1", df$name_and_address)
```